# I want to save a lot of dataframes via a for loop or a function

Tags: r, function, loops, save, rdata

I have different data frame sorted by year in a list

```
mydata<-list()
mydata[["2010"]]<-data.frame(Age=c(12,13),Year=rep("2010",2))
mydata[["2011"]]<-data.frame(Age=c(14,15),Year=rep("2011",2))
mydata[["2012"]]<-data.frame(Age=c(16,17),Year=rep("2012",2))
mydata[["2013"]]<-data.frame(Age=c(18,17),Year=rep("2013",2))
mydata[["2014"]]<-data.frame(Age=c(16,27),Year=rep("2014",2))
```

Instead of saving the list as an RData file, I want to save each object in the list separately.

But first, I want each dataset to be placed in an object indicating the year.

For example for the Year 2010 like this:

```
mydata_2010<-mydata[["2010"]]
save(mydata_2010,file = "mydata_2010.RData")
```

With a for loop or a function, I want to do all this at one go

I succeeded to assign datasets for a particular year to an object indicating the same year

```
for (i in as.character(2010:2012)) {
  assign(paste0(
    "mydata_",i,sep=""
  ),mydata[[i]])
  
}
```

But I dont know to save theses objects via the function `save`

I tried this and it does not works

```
for (i in as.character(2010:2012)) {
      save(assign(paste0(
        "mydata_",i,sep=""
      ),mydata[[i]]), file=paste0("mydata_",i,".RData",sep="")
      
    }
```

Comment: Putting values into variable names is generally a bad idea and it makes things much more difficult to work with in R. Rather than using `save()`, why not use `saveRDS()` which allows you to save one object a time and give it whatever name you want when you read it in.

Comment: Why do you want to take it out of the `list`? It's so much better that way then as separate objects. You can save each data frame from the list very easily, `for(i in seq_along(mydata)) {saveRDS(mydata[[i]], file = paste0(names(mydata)[i], ".RDS"))}`. (And generally `Rdata` is used for saving multiple objects, `RDS` is preferred for single objects.)